# How to defend against hacking if a user submits XML

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a feature where users can submit pure XML in a form. When my server gets the response I will validate it against a XML schema then I store it in the database. I never show the XML on a webpage unless it is in a form for editing.

I use the XML to render html forms or text in a webpage and I will encode the text and never show the actual XML in a browser unless its for editing. Am I subject to a lot of hacking? How can I better defend against this?

For example:

```
<criteria name="Performance" type="textbox">115 Horsepower</criteria>
```

Above will render either a table cell with the word 115 Horsepower in it or it my render a textbox with the word 115 Horsepower in it.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on what you do with that XML.

Comment: When I get the XML from the user I store it in a database once it is validated against my schema. Once, when I need the XML i use it to render text in a webpage or render html forms. But before I send it to the brwser i will encode anything that is rendered.

Comment: "I use the XML to render html forms" - so you interpret the XML in some way. If the language/interpreter is Turing Complete then an attacker can upload an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Think in the direction of some parts of XML missing and some parts repeating twice or more. Take care of those edge cases in your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example of an attack vector for XML content:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs

Comment: Not a billion laughs, 6.8x10^38 laughs.

Comment: Is there a way to defend against this kind of attack?

Comment: The Wiki page links to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcfsx.html which has guidelines for Java (disabling certain features of the XML parser). Presumably similar things would apply in other languages.